# Deleted orders are not removed from grid

Tags: orders, upgrade, order-grid

When I delete an order, it is still listed in orders grid. When I attempt to open it, I get the message

> This order no longer exists.

This behaviour was seemingly introduced by a Magento update: I downloaded the latest version of Magento and overrode the existing files.

Why do the orders still show up in the grid and how can I adjust this?

Comment: What extension are you using to delete the orders? By default, Magento does not have the ability to delete an order out of the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, you have orphaned records in your `sales_flat_order_grid` table that are not in your main order table, `sales_flat_order`. I'm noting two non-native behaviors on your instance of Magento.

1. You can delete orders. Default Magento does not let you delete order. I don't recommend allowing orders to be deleted in live environment.
2. Your MySQL constraint (`CONSTRAINT... ON DELETE CASCADE`) on the grid table has been removed. When an order record is deleted (via any method), The DB is supposed to automatically remove all associated records in `sales_flat_order_*` tables, which include the grid.

You need to do two things to restore integrity to your instance.

1. Re-establish the MySQL constraint. This will prevent orphan order records. This seems more off-topic, I'll offer a solution to your current problem below.
2. Remove the orphan order grid records. Run the following query to remove them.

**Back up DB before running. Test it on a development environment first. I'm not responsible for your data loss.**

```
DELETE 
FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` 
WHERE entity_id IN  (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT g.entity_id
        FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS g
            INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order` AS o
                ON g.`entity_id` = o.`entity_id`
        WHERE g.entity_id IS NULL
    ) AS t
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Mour,
The order has been already deleted from system in table `sales_flat_order`.You need to check here.
I guess that order is in `sales_flat_order_grid` database table but it `doesn't exits on sale_flat_order` table which is `main table of sales order` model[`Mage::getModel('sales/order')`]

see at class [`Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController`](https://github.com/engineyard/magento-ce-1.9/blob/master/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php) where magento is check order is exit or not.

on function initorder

```
protected function _initOrder()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);
        if (!$order->getId()) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('This order no longer exists.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
            return false;
        }
        Mage::register('sales_order', $order);
        Mage::register('current_order', $order);
        return $order;
    }
```

That means order does not delete properly.

**You need to delete those order from  sales_flat_order_grid.**

Comment: then why does it shows in admin > sales > order

Comment: is showing at order grid

Comment: yeah show in order grid but when i click it shows message order does not exists

Answer (score 1):

**The problem is**

The order entry exists in the `sales_flat_order_grid` table but missing in `sales_flat_order` table

**The solution is**

Delete the entries from sales_flat_order_grid table which has no reference in sales_flat_order table

**Run this SQL Query in your database:**

```
DELETE FROM `sales_flat_order_grid`  
WHERE entity_id NOT IN (
   SELECT `entity_id` FROM `sales_flat_order`
);
```

Add a trigger on `sales_flat_order table` on event `AFTER DELETE ON sales_flat_order` if not exists,

```
DELETE FROM sales_flat_order_grid WHERE OLD.entity_id=sales_flat_order_grid.entity_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, But I had the same problem recently. One of my clients has iteratively upgraded from 1.4 up to 1.9 and I have found some orphaned records.

My approach was to check if there are any first.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` WHERE `entity_id` NOT IN (SELECT `entity_id` FROM `sales_flat_order`);
```

Then, delete them:

```
DELETE FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` WHERE `entity_id` NOT IN (SELECT `entity_id` FROM `sales_flat_order`);
```

You can find all orphaned records like this:

```
// `-s` means no clutter around the result, `-N` means no header.

> mysql -s -N -umy_user -p

SELECT 
  CONCAT(
    'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `', TABLE_NAME, '` ',
    'WHERE `', COLUMN_NAME, '` NOT IN (',
    'SELECT `', REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME, '` FROM `', REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, '`',
    ');'
  )
FROM 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE
  REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL
AND 
  CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = '__PUT_DATABASE_NAME_HERE__'
  ;
```

Then you can generate this beauty and finish the job.

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(
    'DELETE FROM `', TABLE_NAME, '` ',
    'WHERE `', COLUMN_NAME, '` NOT IN (',
    'SELECT `', REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME, '` FROM `', REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, '`',
    ');'
  )
FROM 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE
  REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL
AND 
  CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = '__PUT_DATABASE_NAME_HERE__'
  ;
```

Kudos to [kozie](https://gist.github.com/kozie) for [this suggestion](https://gist.github.com/dfelton/042e15a51b9795b25cad0235a1bf9122?permalink_comment_id=2679441#gistcomment-2679441); and
[dfelton](https://gist.github.com/dfelton) for the [orignal idea](https://gist.github.com/dfelton/042e15a51b9795b25cad0235a1bf9122).

You *could* go one more step and create a batch file that iterates over the result using `--execute="DELETE ..."`, but that's definitely out of scope of this answer.